# Is there any way to console log the whole state tree once that reducer updates new state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new to react native.
I would like to know the current state tree once a reducer function has been executed.
I want to know the state tree latest value.

I have set the logic in dumb component that if loggedIn state is true, render page 2, if it is false, render page 1.

Is dumb component not knowing the update, or is that is not the right way to arrange the flow?

My action is when i init the store, i dispatch an action to check if there's access token in user local storage. if it is exists, update the state..
But somehow it seems like the state does not updated.

EDITED:

This is my reducer

```
const initialState = {
    token: null,
    username: null,
    loggedIn: false
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        // Reducer does not handle API type of actions
        case types.STORE_TOKEN:
            AsyncStorage.setItem(localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(action.payload.token))
            return {
                token: action.payload.token,
                username : action.payload.username,
                loggedIn: true
            }
        case types.GET_TOKEN:
            AsyncStorage.getItem(localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN).then((storage) =>{
                if(!storage){ return state }
                return {
                    token: storage,
                    loggedIn: true
                }
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a function [getState](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#getState), you can use it to check the updated values.

Comment: It does not updated..
i guess i have done mistake in reducer..

Comment: i have updated my reducer @MayankShukla

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you add a middleware for logging. [Here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) is example. If you use [redux](http://redux.js.org/), you can do it in the following way:

```
1. Install [redux-logger](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-logger) package:
(npm i --save redux-logger or yarn add redux-logger)

2. Add to file where you create store following imports:

import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'

3. Create your store like this:

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(createLogger()))
```

When you will have done it, in the console browser you'll see something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a middle-ware in your `createStore` function like the code below. It consoles the all actions and current state and next state. It's so simple to use and helpful.

**logger.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const DO_NOT_LOG = [
  'EFFECT_TRIGGERED', 'EFFECT_RESOLVED', 'EFFECT_REJECTED',
]

export default store => next => action => {
  if ((!_.includes(DO_NOT_LOG, action.type))) {
    console.info('Dispatching: ', action)
  }

  let result = next(action)

  if ((!_.includes(DO_NOT_LOG, action.type))) {
    console.log('Next State: ', store.getState())
  }

  return result
}
```

**`createStore` function:**

```
import logger from './middleware/logger'
...
const middleware = [logger]
  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      autoRehydrate(),
    ),
  )
```